# Transforming a dataframe in bool values based on other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

```py
ytest.groupby(ytest.index.get_level_values(0)).transform(lambda x: x > Value)
```

How can I make this work if "Value is in other dataframe ?

```py
ytest pandas series
CNPJ                          
00.089.915/0001-15  2020-07-31   -0.095673
00.400.490/0001-13  2020-07-31    0.404326
00.840.008/0001-66  2020-07-31    0.159334
01.353.626/0001-44  2020-07-31    0.013718
01.541.649/0001-82  2020-07-31   -0.617779
                                    ...   
35.609.786/0001-23  2022-08-31   -0.857614
35.617.938/0001-30  2022-08-31   -0.463720
35.618.055/0001-44  2022-08-31   -0.473224
35.636.909/0001-15  2022-08-31    0.580094
35.650.636/0001-63  2022-08-31   -2.298512


value df


CNPJ (index)         Mean
00.089.915/0001-15  -0.082733
00.400.490/0001-13  0.149776
00.840.008/0001-66  0.073911
01.353.626/0001-44  0.164392
01.541.649/0001-82  -0.069199
... ...
35.609.786/0001-23  -0.877253
35.617.938/0001-30  0.194214
35.618.055/0001-44  0.204535
35.636.909/0001-15  1.161631
35.650.636/0001-63  -0.266092
919 rows × 1 columns
```

So the main goal here: if the row value of ytest for every "00.089.915/0001-15" is greater than it's historical mean "-0.082733" the new dataframe should display True

Comment: The inputs are not clear, please provide small by complete and reproducible DataFrame constructors. It's hard to tell what is index, columns… at the moment

Comment: Sorry for the bad explanation. In value df the "CNPJ" is the index and in ytest series the date and 'CNPJ' are indexes.

Comment: I strongly advice to improve clarity of your question, what is the historical mean ?